# Execute a function when the page (component) loads in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

How do I execute a function when the page (component) loads in Vue 3? I'm exporting the function from a `.js` file, but I need it to be executed when a specific component is loaded in the UI. In the components Currently I'm working with `<script setup>`.

```html
<script setup>
// Example
import { someFunction } from "./js/allowFunctions.js"
</script>
```

I tried changing the `<script setup>` to only `<script>`, but it could take me hours to refactor a lot of code in my project.

Comment: You don't use someFunction anywhere. Importing a module that is not used is generally a no-op. Did you try to call someFunction inside onMounted? It's unclear if it's the only difficulty here

Comment: @EstusFlask I putted someFunction like example. The point is that idk where to put it to execute it  when the page loads, and I can´t put onMounted in a <script setup> tag

Comment: Not sure what did make you think so, but you can, https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted . Otherwise script setup would be limited and pointless. In case this solves the problem, that's it. There's a chance that this is XY problem, as running scripts that are unaware of a framework can lead to bugs and memory leaks.

Comment: @EstusFlask You´re right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute a function within your component as soon as the component is loaded, you can use the lifecycle hook [`onMounted`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted) and execute your function within it.

For example:

```html
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from "vue"
import { someFunction } from "./js/allowFunctions.js"

onMounted(() => {
  someFunction()
})
</script>
```